# Can a Minotaur wear (and benefit from) Horseshoes of Flame?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, minotaur

**Related:** [Can a Centaur wear (and benefit from) magical horseshoes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71857/can-a-centaur-wear-and-benefit-from-magical-horseshoes)

---

**Item in Question**

The Horseshoes of Flame (Savage Species, page 57) state:

> An ordinary horse wearing these horseshoes may transform up to three times per day, for up to 7 hours each time, into a creature resembling a nightmare.

There is no text stating "All four horseshoes must be worn..." like the [Horseshoes of Speed](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#horseshoesofspeed) and [Horseshoes of a Zephyr](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#horseshoesofaZephyr) state.

This is either an oversight, like many other oversights in *Savage Species*, or is on purpose.

---

**Creature in Question**

As we know of 3rd Edition, a [minotaur](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/minotaur.htm) looks like this:

[image: minotaur]

---

**Dilemma**

It has hooves, but only has two. The text of the magic item explicitly states horse - not "animal" or any other creature.

Looking at the stats boost (+2 Dex, +10 Int, +6 Charisma), I am rather hesitant to tell my player "go for it" whenever deep down I am thinking, "oh hell no."

---

**Questions**

1. Can a minotaur in fact wear and benefit from the Horseshoes of Flame?
2. Would the minotaur require a Use Magic Device to activate them?
3. Does the magic item require the wearer to actually be a horse?
4. Does "creature resembling a nightmare" keep the general shape of original creature; nightmarish minotaur - or an actual nightmare?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The text is clear.  The horseshoes may only be used by ordinary horses, and any user transforms into a 'creature resembling a Nightmare' (though any such changes, are, of course, superficial).  However, a DC 25 UMD check allows a Minotaur (or any other creature, regardless of whether it has hooves or not) to count as an ordinary horse for the purposes of the item via the *Emulate a Race* option.