# Can a Centaur wear and benefit from magical boots, slippers, and other non-horseshoe footwear?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, equipment, centaur

It seems agreed upon that [Centaur](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/centaur) player characters (from *Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica* & *Mythic Odysseys of Theros*) can wear, and benefit from, the magic items *horseshoes of speed* and *horseshoes of a zephyr*.

But what about other types of footwear: *slippers of spider climbing*, *boots of speed*, etc? Could a Centaur player character benefit from those too?

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Can creatures without hands (and as a consequence fingers) use rings?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103151)"

Comment: Closely related 5e question: [Can animal-like playable races wear shoes/boots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119716/can-animal-like-playable-races-wear-shoes-boots) Related 3.5e question: [Can a Centaur wear (and benefit from) magical horseshoes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71857/can-a-centaur-wear-and-benefit-from-magical-horseshoes)

Comment: At very the least you'd think the centaur should need **2 pair** of those boots for all its feet for them to work.

Comment: @T.E.D. Can a quadruped benefit from two pairs of magic boots is interesting enough to be its own question.

Answer (score 25):

### It depends on DM discretion

There is a section in the DMG on "[Wearing and Wielding Items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems)" (page 140), which states that items must we worn in the intended fashion and that:

> In most cases, a magic item that's meant to be worn can fit a creature regardless of size or build.

However, this doesn't necessarily extend to boots intended for feet fitting onto hooves. There is, in fact, some help in the last paragraph of that section (you'd be excused for missing it because it's on the next page):

> When a nonhumanoid tries to wear an item, use your discretion as to whether the item functions as intended. A ring placed on a tentacle might work, but a yuan-ti with a snakelike tail instead of legs can't wear boots.

So it comes down to DM discretion whether a centaur's hooves are sufficiently foot-like for any magical boots, slippers, or other footwear.

Comment: If the GM wanted to allow it, it would be within the GM's discretion to have a player hire some kind of craftman to convert the boots into leg covers.

Comment: @ikegami There is some background too that many magical items reform to suit the wearer - so probably not necessary. But, the DM might tie it in to the story or world setting as a side-quest in itself. :)

Comment: @Senmurv, Yes, of course. I should have been clearer. The side quest angle is exactly what I was thinking :) Also, that it would provide the GM a nice in-game way of picking and choosing which items could be adapted, and how many. Both of these ideas are rooted in the fact that a craftman able to do the conversion might not be readily available.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that, as it was answered in
the following link, as fas as they wear them its fine.

[Can creatures without hands (and as a consequence fingers) use rings?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103151/can-creatures-without-hands-and-as-a-consequence-fingers-use-rings?rq=1)

> ### Rings have to be worn
>
> **... just not necessarily on fingers**
>
> From Volo's Guide to Monsters p.15
>
> > ... a beholder could wear magic rings on its eyestalks ... and the items function as they would if used by a humanoid.

Comment: I would argue that the rules are a little less forgiving than that. The rules state that items must be worn in their intended fashion, with _some_ exceptions like the beholder's eyestalks. I can't just strap Boots of Elvenkind to my shoulders and expect to move silently (Not to say that putting boots on a centaur is as radical as that, but the sentiment of "Wear it and you're good" is a little misleading).

Comment: @TheLittlePeace: Indeed. As noted in Someone_Evil's answer, the DM's rules on ["Wearing and Wielding Items"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#WearingandWieldingItems) state: "A magic item meant to be worn must be donned in the intended fashion: boots go on the feet, [...]" and "In most cases, [it] can fit a creature regardless of size or build.", but "When a nonhumanoid tries to wear an item, use your discretion as to whether the item functions as intended. A ring placed on a tentacle might work, but a creature with a snakelike tail instead of legs can't wear boots."